# Why does Org-mode ignore the :noexport: tags

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have set up my Emacs configuration in org-mode like in [this](http://mescal.imag.fr/membres/arnaud.legrand/misc/init.php).

So the code under the headlines tagged `:noexport:` should not be exported to the `init.el` file. But it does though I have

```
...
#+OPTIONS: tags:t
#+EXPORT_SELECT_TAGS: export
#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
...
#+TAGS: ... noexport(n)
```

in the header and though `C-h v org-export-exclude-tags` also shows the correct value:

```
org-export-exclude-tags is a variable defined in `ox.el'.
Its value is ("noexport")
...
```

Does anybody have any idea why the `:noexport:` tag is ignored when I call `org-babel-load-file` typing `C-c i`?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

The `EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS` directive is applied when exporting the org file to another format.

`org-babel-load-file` does not use the exporter; it rather uses `org-tangle`.

In order to exclude a source block from tangling, you should add `:tangle no` to the actual source code blocks you don't want included in your initialization.

Reference [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html#Extracting-source-code).